generate text with the same spacing as y-ticks in matplotlib
i want generate text with the same spacing as y-ticks in matplotlib
Failed to reach by axes.bar_label
my code
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style('white')
    
s = pd.Series({'John': 5, 'Amy': 7, 'Elizabeth': 6, 'James': 10, 'Roy': 5})

ax1 = s.plot(kind='barh', figsize=(6, 3), width=.1)
labels = ax1.bar_label(ax1.containers[0], fontsize=10)

for label in labels:
    label.set_ha('right')

ax1.set_xticks([])
sns.despine(bottom=True, left=True)

i want generate 6 text with the same spacing as y-ticks in matplotlib
ex. The 6 texts are positioned 0.01 (based on transAxes) above their respective yticks


Update
i get desired output from following code:
for i in range(len(s)):
    plt.text(s[i], i + 0.02, f'{s[i]}', transform=ax1.transData, va='bottom', fontsize=8, ha='right', color='gray')

If there is a way to solve it with axes.bar_label instead of plt.text, I'm still waiting, so please reply. Thanks.
